# Why is rails application always running in development mode?

Tags: apache-2.2, ruby-on-rails, phusion-passenger

I created rails application, and everything appears to be working fine, but I can't seem to figure out how to run the application in `production` mode.  I specified in the `example.com.conf` (Apache configuration file) for the site, `RailsEnv production` I then restarted Apache, and restarted the rails app by running the following command in the rails root directory, `touch tmp/restart.txt`

I'm running Apache 2.x, mod_rails 4.0.26, and the rails app is 3.2.15

Answer (score 1):

By default, Passenger sets the value to `production`:

http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#PassengerAppEnv

check your `environment.rb` and your .bashrc, you might be setting the RAILS_ENV somewhere else.